# Can I get windows xp drivers for lenovo b5130 laptop?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I have a b51-30 Lenovo laptop with N3050 cpu and 2 GB ram.. and windows 10 ..
With this poor specifications it runs windows 10 slowly..
I want to try windows xp on it .. but there is no drivers for win XP on Lenovo web site .. what can I do ?

Comment: Look for models with similar hardware that do have drivers for Windows XP or give Windows 7 (32-bit) a shot. I'd guess that drivers for Windows 7 would be available and/or you might be able to use Windows 10 drivers on it.

Comment: Why not use Windows 7? After all it is still supported, unlike Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

There are drivers on drp.su, which are same ones used by iobit driver booster. However, only some. No wifi driver. You could try windows xp integral edition which has universal ahci, acpi, usb 3.0 and other drivers, to bypass 7b bsod error, but even then, even with help of easy2boot and winsetupfromusb, my laptop shuts down at early stage of setup, when I have choice to install or repair.